# Unity Change Scene with button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been having problems with my code for unity. I'm using C Sharp and Unity 5.0.2f Personal Edition. Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonEvent : MonoBehaviour {
    public void LoadScene(int SceneToChangeTo){
        Application.LoadLevel (SceneToChangeTo);
    }
}
```

This should change the to an integer scene but when I go to the `button.onclick()` in the inspector and add the script nothing comes up about changing scene (Note: The script is under "_Manager" (An empty `GameObject`))

Comment: Make sure you add your scene in Build Setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a listener for your button and make sure you put a value in numberOfLevel variable and assign your button to MyButton in the inspector or you will get a null reference exception

```
[SerializeField] private Button MyButton = null; // assign in the editor
public int numberoflevel;

void Start() { MyButton.onClick.AddListener(() => { changeScene(numberoflevel);});
}

 public void LoadScene(int SceneToChangeTo){
        Application.LoadLevel (SceneToChangeTo);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I found the LoadScene() I was just messing around trying to find it and it turned out it was right in front of my eyes

Comment: actually, what would I have to do to make a button that could exit the game

Comment: in my answer i made a button that changed scenes so instead of calling change scene make another method for exit like this `void Start() { MyButton.onClick.AddListener(() => { quit();});
}

 public void quit(){
      Application.Quit();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
        using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
///***///
        public void LoadGameLevel(int SceneToChangeTo)
        { SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneToChangeTo);
        }
    //or
        public void LoadGameLevel(string SceneName)
        { SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneName);
        }
```

note: Worked in OnMouseDown() and Unity Ui and other